# How can I have control over my sleep?

Tags: sleeping

So, I'm having a problem:

If I wake at 8 am in the morning, I usually wake up 1 hour later at 9 am. The worst part is that even when I put on my alarm, I don't even remember closing it. So it seems like I have closed it while being half a sleep or something of this sort. I usually go to sleep these days at 1 or 2 am.

Any ideas on how to have control over this?

Comment: Problems managing your sleep patterns is a better fit for our [health site](http://health.stackexchange.com). Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Move your alarm clock to the other side of the room from where you sleep. This will force you to get out of bed and wake up.